# Semantic segmentation with amazon AWS sagemaker

Tags: machine-learning, amazon-sagemaker, semantic-segmentation

Hello dear communty

I wanted to share my experience with training and deploying an FCN algorithm using Amazon SageMaker. I followed the tutorial provided on the AWS Machine Learning Blog titled "Semantic Segmentation Data Labeling and Model Training using Amazon SageMaker" (https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/machine-learning/semantic-segmentation-data-labeling-and-model-training-using-amazon-sagemaker/).

The training process went smoothly, and I was able to achieve good results. Even the inference phase within SageMaker worked like a charm. However, when I downloaded the trained model and ran it with a Python script on an Ubuntu machine, I noticed that the results were not the same as those obtained during inference on SageMaker. I'm wondering if I missed something during the setup process.

I have the model in a .tar.gz format, which contains the following files:

1. hyperparams.json
2. model_algo-1
3. model_best.params

To run the model, I used the following code:

```
import mxnet as mx
from mxnet import image
from gluoncv.data.transforms.presets.segmentation import test_transform
import gluoncv
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.colors as colors

# Use GPU if one exists; otherwise, use CPU
ctx = mx.gpu() if mx.context.num_gpus() else mx.cpu()

model = gluoncv.model_zoo.FCN(11)
model.load_parameters('./model/model_algo-1', ignore_extra=True)

# Move the model to the GPU
model.collect_params().reset_ctx(ctx)

# Load the test image
img = image.imread('./test/test_143.png')
original_img = Image.open('./test/test_143.png')

img1 = test_transform(img, ctx)
img1 = img1.astype('float32')

# Perform inference
output = model.predict(img1)
predict = mx.nd.squeeze(mx.nd.argmax(output, 1)).asnumpy()

# Create a figure with two subplots
fig, axs = plt.subplots(1, 2, figsize=(12, 6))

# Plot the original image in the first subplot
axs[0].imshow(original_img)
axs[0].axis('off')
axs[0].set_title('Original')

# Plot the predicted mask in the second subplot
axs[1].imshow(predict, alpha=0.8, cmap='viridis')
axs[1].axis('off')
axs[1].set_title('Predicted Mask')

# Adjust the spacing between subplots
plt.tight_layout()

# Display the plot
plt.show()
```

I'm curious to know if the inference in SageMaker uses a pretrained model, or if there are any additional steps I need to take to ensure consistent results between SageMaker and my local setup.

If anyone has experience with this or can offer any insights, I would greatly appreciate it! Thanks in advance!

I tried training an FCN algorithm using SageMaker and followed the tutorial mentioned in the AWS Machine Learning Blog. During training, I expected the model to learn and generate accurate results. The training process went well, and the model performed satisfactorily during inference within SageMaker.

However, when I downloaded the trained model and ran it on an Ubuntu machine using a Python script, the results were not as expected. The output from the inference on my local setup was different from what I observed in SageMaker. I was expecting the same or similar results, but that was not the case.

I used the provided Python code to load the model, preprocess the test image, and perform inference. I visualized the original image and the predicted mask using matplotlib. The code executed without any errors, but the predicted mask did not match the results obtained in SageMaker.

In summary, I tried running the downloaded model on my local machine and expected the same results as the inference in SageMaker. However, the actual outcome was different, and the predicted mask did not align with what I had observed in SageMaker.

Update:
Here is the sagemaker code to do the inference

```
training_job_name = 'ss-notebook-demo-2022-02-12-03-37-27-151'
ss_estimator = sagemaker.estimator.Estimator.attach(training_job_name)
ss_predictor = ss_estimator.deploy(initial_instance_count=1, instance_type="ml.c5.xlarge")

from PIL import Image
import numpy as np


class ImageDeserializer(sagemaker.deserializers.BaseDeserializer):
    """Deserialize a PIL-compatible stream of Image bytes into a numpy pixel array"""

    def __init__(self, accept="image/png"):
        self.accept = accept

    @property
    def ACCEPT(self):
        return (self.accept,)

    def deserialize(self, stream, content_type):
        """Read a stream of bytes returned from an inference endpoint.
        Args:
            stream (botocore.response.StreamingBody): A stream of bytes.
            content_type (str): The MIME type of the data.
        Returns:
            mask: The numpy array of class labels per pixel
        """
        try:
            return np.array(Image.open(stream))
        finally:
            stream.close()


ss_predictor.deserializer = ImageDeserializer(accept="image/png")
ss_predictor.serializer = sagemaker.serializers.IdentitySerializer("image/jpeg")

with open(filename, "rb") as imfile:
    imbytes = imfile.read()
%%time

cls_mask = ss_predictor.predict(imbytes)

print(type(cls_mask))
print(cls_mask.shape)

plt.imshow(cls_mask, cmap="jet")
plt.show()
```

Comment: Could you post the code for the preprocessing (both on AWS and local)? I am pretty sure there is a small issue with the preprocessing/something you are missing when doing the preprocessing. Indeed, if you downloaded the model and loaded it locally it should not behave differently on Cloud vs on-premise.

Comment: I just update the code of sagemaker in the post, I am not sure if the ss_deploy or sagemaker.estimator is the reason of why the results is better.